# How to render different data every time upon clicking each item from a list of .map items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Th question is so confusing in itself but all I want to implement that I've three restaurants data in a database and I'm displaying their names on three cards by calling .map method on restaurants names list, now I want to do something like whenever someone click on a card it will take him to a page where he can find all the information about that specific restaurant, it's dishes and should be able to rate them, so how this routing take place? Should I have to create three separate pages but what if I have more than three so it would be a mess? or there's a way to dynamically display different data upon clicking different cards? for your reference, I'm using MERN Stack for this project.

Comment: This is definitely possible if you're using React, just create a generic component and pass the data in as a prop. If you can provide any code that you've written for this we will be able to help solve the issue quicker :)

Comment: With react-router, you would wrap the clickable restaurant cards in the `<Link>` component. You pass an ID or name or something that identifies your restaurants (something that is the primary key in your DB ideally). Then you add a `<Route>` component that takes that ID as parameter. It would be a generic component that displays the details of a restaurant. Clicking on a card would then go to that route. Maybe read a react-router tutorial before attempting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , you don't have to create separate pages , you just need to create a single detailsPage component and pass the required props containing card details(restaurant) you clicked.

So basically you will first initialize a local state object in your component which displays cards like this :

```
this.state = {
  restaurantName : '',
  restuarantId: '',
  showDetails: false,
}
```

Then bind a click handler on your cards to some function like :

```
const onCardClick = (id,name) => {
   this.setState({
    showDetails: true,
    restuarantName: name,
    restaurantId: id
  })
}
```

Now inside your render method, just render your details component with a if condition so it shows up only when showDetails is set to true, and it recieves appropriate id and name

```
return(){
  .....
  // your previous code
.....
    {
        this.state.showDetails && 
         <DetailsPage id=this.state.id name=this.state.name />
    }
  }
```

Note : The above way is useful if you want to show details page as a pop up window or below the cards , if you want to route to a new page then you can do conditional routing , but idea remains same that you create a single component and pass appropriate props to it.